# How to create rhombus described on rectangle

Tags: geometry, rectangles

Let's say I have a rectangle of width w and height h centered at coordinate origin. How I can create rhombus described on this rectangle? Additional requirement is that rhombus width should be twice as height.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Clue: you need that rectangle corner point `(w/2, h/2)` belongs to segment `(0, a)-(2*a, 0)`.

So write line equation for this segment, substitute corner coordinates into that equation, solve it for unknown `a` parameter (half of vertical diagonal of the rhombus)